# JQPlot setting ticks and then re-labelling them

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I want to use a linear scale starting from 1 to 20 to format the x-axis ticks and, but then I want to re-label them with different values. Is this possible? I don't see any 'ticklabel' fields.

I'm currently setting the ticks with the `ticks:array`, where the array contains data that isn't spaced by the same value. What I want to do is `ticks:[1,2...20]` and then label the ticks with the values in the array.

For example, right now, my array contains data like "100, 121, 125, 128, 140". I want the x-axis to be evenly spaced, and still display "100, 121, 125, 128, 140".

Here is the code for the x-axis that I'm using:

```
xaxis :
{
    tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions :
    {
        angle : -90,
        textColor : '#FFA500',
        fontSize : '1em',
        fontFamily : '"Trebuchet   MS",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'
    },
    label : "Value",
    pad : 0,
    min : minValue,
    max : maxValue,
    ticks : values,
    autoscale : false
}
```

`values` is an array that contains the values I want to display on the x-axis, but I want the distance to be the same for the values on the x-axis

Here is the entire thing:

```
var plot = $.jqplot (chartID ,[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5],
        {
            title: "5 Items" ,

              series:[
                      {
                        label:val[0],
                        lineWidth:2, 
                        markerOptions: { style:'dimaond' }
                      },
                      {
                          label:val[1],
                            lineWidth:2, 
                            markerOptions: { style:'dimaond' }
                      },
                      {
                          label:val[2],
                            markerOptions: { style:"circle" }
                      }
                      ,
                      {
                          label:val[3],
                            markerOptions: { style:"circle" }
                      }
                      ,
                      {
                          label:val[4],
                            markerOptions: { style:"circle" }
                      }
                      ]
                      ,
               grid: {
                          background: '#fffdf6',   
                          borderColor: '#999999'     
                      },              

                  axes: {
                      // options for each axis are specified in seperate
                        // option objects.
                      xaxis: {
                          tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                          tickOptions: {
                              angle: -90,
                              textColor:'#FFA500',
                              fontSize:'1em',
                              fontFamily: '"Trebuchet MS",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'
                          },
                        label: "Value",
                        pad: 0,
                        min:minValue,
                        max:maxValue,
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: values,
                        autoscale:false
                      },
                      yaxis: {              
                        min:minTime,
                        max:maxTime,
                          tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                          tickOptions: {
                              formatString: "%#.2f",
                              textColor:'#FFA500',
                              fontSize:'1em',
                              fontFamily: '"Trebuchet MS",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'
                          }
                      }
              },
              legend:{
                  show:true,
                  location:'se',
                  labels:vals,
                  placement:"insideGrid"
              }
        });
```

Comment: can you please share your code or any screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer` would solve your problem.
Please add the jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer.js file to your page too.

Eample for your question: [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jzwn9/1/)

Example: [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9nAd2/1/)

```
xaxis :
{
    tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions :
    {
        angle : -90,
        textColor : '#FFA500',
        fontSize : '1em',
        fontFamily : '"Trebuchet   MS",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'
    },
    label : "Value",
    pad : 0,
    min : minValue,
    max : maxValue,
    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    ticks : values,
    autoscale : false
}
```

Comment: This seems to fix the x-axis scale, but none of my lines shows now.

Comment: @sportsfan72 Please use the jsFiddle link my my answer, it will help you to solve that problem.

Comment: I've looked at it, but I'm not sure why no values are being displayed for the lines now after adding that line of code. Do you have any idea? I've added my y-axis code if that helps.

Comment: i would have to look at your whole code, before i can say anything.

Comment: did you include the jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer.js file in your code.
Can you also provide me some values of `val` variables

Comment: I've included the file. The labels val[] are strings, they are names.values for the y-axis are times, measured in seconds. And on the x-axis values are similar to dates, but dates are not used.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out why mine isn't working, but this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try tickOptions with -  showLabel : 'true'

```
 ticks: [],      // a 1D [val1, val2, ...], or 2D [[val, label], [val, label], ...]
                    // array of ticks to use.  Computed automatically.
 numberTicks: undefined, 

 tickOptions: {
        mark: 'outside',    // Where to put the tick mark on the axis
                            // 'outside', 'inside' or 'cross',
        showMark: true,
        showGridline: true, // wether to draw a gridline (across the whole grid) at this tick,
        markSize: 4,        // length the tick will extend beyond the grid in pixels.  For
                            // 'cross', length will be added above and below the grid boundary,
        show: true,         // wether to show the tick (mark and label),
        showLabel: true,    // wether to show the text label at the tick,
        formatString: '',   // format string to use with the axis tick formatter
    }
```

Comment: I updated the question, "right now, my array contains data like "100, 121, 125, 128, 140". I want the x-axis to be evenly spaced, and still display "100, 121, 125, 128, 140"." I can display the ticks, but if i do it with a linear scale, my spacing is fine but the labels aren't what I want them to be, and if i use my array, the labels are fine but the spacing on the graph isn't what I want it to be.